# If both adds newline after message, What is the difference between print() and stdout.writeln() in dart?

Tags: dart

here is my simple dart code.

```
import 'dart:io';

main(){
    print("Hello World");
    stdout.writeln("Another Hello World");
}
```

output:

```
Hello World   //Prints newline by default. 
Another Hello World    //Also print newline after this.
```

If both functions print a newline after printing, then what is the difference between both of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the DartVM the behaviours are the same. But when Dart code runs in browser you cannot use `stdout`. [dart:io library](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) can not be used in Browser-based applications. [`print`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/print.html) been part of the core library it can be used everywhere.

A little difference (also on VM) is that [`print` can be overriden with Zone](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/zones#example-overriding-print).

Answer (score 0):

For `print()` it brings the cursor to the next line as the work ends there, and another hand `stdout.write` makes to stay the cursor at the same line, yet it adds the `newline`.